# Unable to find a suitable frontend mobile framework for cakephp2

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, web-frontend

I'm currently planning to build a mobile friendly website via cakephp2. But the problem is that I cannot find a good & beautiful frontend framework suitable for cakephp2. Bootstrap is ok, but it looks plain boring. Are there some beautiful frontend framework that could easily be implemented in cakephp2? What do you recommend? I dont see so much tutorial on setting up frontend frame work to cakephp2. I would love to hear from you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid rely only in frameworks to get your system/app identity, because it's so subjective the world of UX/UI and it's important search/study more about that and customize your frontend with some objects that you created by your own - the main thing of a frontend framework is improve your dev timing without reinventing the wheel. Said that, I recommend 3 other frameworks besides Bootstrap:

- [Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/)

Simple verbose, clean looks, I like Semantic for your simplicity and easy structure looks. And has a great implementation of themes concept, which leads to what you want.

- [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)

To mobile, it's one shot solution. Very responsible - that's your philosophy.

- [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/)

UX focused, it's better to who works heavily with that, understanding some concepts and improving them.

What I love? [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com/) - crude, fast, clean.

PS: To be honest, using CakePHP or other backend framework should be nothing to do with your front frameworks.

Comment: Thank you! They all look great! Now a new problem arises...I want to use them all!

Answer (score 1):

[ionic](https://ionicframework.com/) and [framework7](https://framework7.io/) look pretty neat to me